# One Nginx Error Page to Rule Them All

Tags: php, nginx, error-handling

### The Dream

I have a number of server blocks that come and go with the wind. I would really like to create and maintain one PHP template to handle ALL server related errors (404, 403, etc) ...no matter on which block or under which domain they occur, and without having to setup standard server error pages on a block by block basis.

I am detailing my setup here with the thought that it might also be a solution others find useful and would like to implement.

### The Setup

In `/etc/nginx/` I have a file called `errors.conf`, which should try and pass errors to a `error.php` file in `/var/www/admin/public`

---

```
# All the errors...

error_page 401      /error.php?c=401;
error_page 403      /error.php?c=403;
error_page 404      /error.php?c=404;
error_page 500      /error.php?c=500;
error_page 502 503 504  /error.php?c=50x;

# Serve error.php from www/admin/public

location = /error.php {
    root /var/www/admin/public;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    auth_basic off;
}
```

`errors.conf` is included in every server block, which would typically look something like this.

```
server { 

    listen       80; 
    server_name  demosite.domain.com; 
    root   /var/www/demosite/public; 
    access_log  /var/www/demosite/logs/demosite.domain.com.access.log; 
    error_log  /var/www/demosite/logs/demosite.domain.com.error.log; 

    location = /favicon.ico { 
        return          204; 
        access_log      off; 
        log_not_found   off; 
    } 

    location / { 
        index  index.html index.htm index.php; 
    } 

    include errors.conf; 

    location ^~ /public/errors { 
        auth_basic      off;             
        allow           all; 
    } 

    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket    
    location ~ \.php$ { 
        try_files       $uri =404; 
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
        fastcgi_index   index.php; 
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 

}
```

And where a very simple, un-styled version of the actual error page (`error.php`) might look like this...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

      <?php

      // Map error code to message string
      $_err = Array("401" => "Authorization Required",
          "403" => "Access Restricted",
          "404" => "File Not Found",
          "500" => "Some Sort of Server Error",
          "50x" => "Temporarily Unavailable");

      // Get the error string
      function errorString($error)
      {
          global $_err;

          foreach ($_err as $key => $val) {
              if ($key == $error)
                  return $val;
          }

          return "Unknown Error";
      }

      isset($_GET['c']) or die("Unknown Error");
      $error = $_GET['c'];
      $str = errorString($error);

      ?>


    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?= $error ?> - <?= $str ?></title>
      </head>

      <body>

      <main>
        <h1><?= $error ?> – <?= $str ?></h1>
        <h3>Something went wrong. <b>Horribly wrong.</b></h3>
      </main>

      </body>
    </html>
```

### The Outcome

What happens now with, for example, a 404 error is that the `error.php` file is not executed, but *downloaded*. And the title of the downloaded file is the last segment of the URL.

So when trying to access, for example, `demosite.domain.com/blah/some_file.html` a download of our `error.php` file named **some_file.html** will be initiated.

So we're close! And I am sure the fix is relatively simple. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

---

#### Update

fastcgi.conf is as follows...

```
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

    # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
    fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: Your `location = /error.php` block is probably wrong. What is `fastcgi.conf` and does it include all of the statements from the `location ~ \.php$` block?

Comment: Thanks. But wrong how? I added contents of fastcgi.conf at the bottom of the original post. Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no fastcgi_pass statement

Comment: I looked at [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_pass) but I'm not quite sure I follow what should be done about it, and why it would explain that PHP is otherwise working as it should – it's only the grand plan for error handling across blocks that is falling flat on it's face. Thanks for any more hints you can provide.

Comment: I solved it with Service Side Includes. It's maybe a similar solution as with PHP. Wrote a blog post about it https://blog.adriaan.io/one-nginx-error-page-to-rule-them-all.html

Comment: @adriaan Is this working ? Where should be define this mapping ? Can you update the page with steps.